# Consolibyte PHP QuickBooks Desktop - Client found response content

Tags: php, soap, quickbooks

I am using the Consolibyte SDK. It's working fine on my local server (XAMPP), but when I move it to my company's Laravel-based system, the web connector says "Authentication Failed". I have the route set up and everything, and tested it in Postman, and it does return:

```
SOAP-ENV:Client Bad Request: 6: No XML content to parse.
```

However, I got the same message on my local server. Here's the QuickBooks WebConnector log file:

```
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'QuickBooks Integrator' has STARTED
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Password management - Started
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Password management - Ended
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : Performing SCHEDULED UPDATE for application = QuickBooks Integrator
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: QuickBooks Integrator
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): QuickBooks Integrator
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://7c24f463.ngrok.io/v2/financialhub/qbwc
20181129.22:33:07 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20181129.22:33:09 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : XML dump follows: -

Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:serverVersionResponse><ns1:serverVersionResult>PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /v2/financialhub/qbwc</ns1:serverVersionResult></ns1:serverVersionResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.

20181129.22:33:09 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20181129.22:33:09 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.2.0.94">
20181129.22:33:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : XML dump follows: -

Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:clientVersionResponse><ns1:clientVersionResult></ns1:clientVersionResult></ns1:clientVersionResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.

20181129.22:33:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20181129.22:33:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks Integrator', username = 'quickbooks'
20181129.22:33:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : XML dump follows: -

QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticateResponse><ns1:authenticateResult><ns1:string>7515a133a99e8bf659bc1bf77e368e37</ns1:string>
<ns1:string>none</ns1:string>
</ns1:authenticateResult></ns1:authenticateResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services

20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : UpdateThisScheduledApp() : QBWC1031: Update completed with some error. Application has been notified of the error accordingly. See QWCLog for further information.
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: QuickBooks Integrator
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): QuickBooks Integrator
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://7c24f463.ngrok.io/v2/financialhub/qbwc
20181129.22:33:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20181129.22:33:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : XML dump follows: -

Actual error received from web service for serverVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:serverVersionResponse><ns1:serverVersionResult>PHP QuickBooks SOAP Server v3.0 at /v2/financialhub/qbwc</ns1:serverVersionResult></ns1:serverVersionResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-serverVersion.

20181129.22:33:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : This application does not contain support for serverVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20181129.22:33:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.2.0.94">
20181129.22:33:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : XML dump follows: -

Actual error received from web service for clientVersion call: <Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:clientVersionResponse><ns1:clientVersionResult></ns1:clientVersionResult></ns1:clientVersionResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--.>. For backward compatibility of all webservers, QBWC will catch all errors under app-not-supporting-clientVersion.

20181129.22:33:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application does not contain support for clientVersion. Allowing update operation for backward compatibility.
20181129.22:33:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'QuickBooks Integrator', username = 'quickbooks'
20181129.22:33:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="quickbooks"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20181129.22:33:16 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : XML dump follows: -

QBWC1012: Authentication failed due to following error message.
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
             xmlns:ns1="http://developer.intuit.com/">
                <SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:authenticateResponse><ns1:authenticateResult><ns1:string>5d989f16c2eda5ca46f3157752b54893</ns1:string>
<ns1:string>none</ns1:string>
</ns1:authenticateResult></ns1:authenticateResponse>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
            </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
--.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.authenticate(String strUserName, String strPassword)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.authenticate(String UserName, String Password)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_authenticate(String& ticket, String& companyFileName)
Source = System.Web.Services

20181129.22:33:16 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20181129.22:33:16 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20181129.22:33:16 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdate() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

All the requests return a 200 HTTP response error, and I don't see any PHP errors. I have error_reporting set to E_ALL and E_STRICT; in fact, I basically copied the **example_web_connector.php** file verbatim.

This is what my SOAP server says:

```
QuickBooks PHP DevKit Server v3.0 at /v2/financialhub/qbwc
   (c) "Keith Palmer" <keith@consolibyte.com> 
   Visit us at: http://www.ConsoliBYTE.com/ 

Use the QuickBooks Web Connector to access this SOAP server.

QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server::handle() parameters: 
 - $return = 1
 - $debug  = 1

Misc. information: 
 - Logging: 3
 - Timezone: America/Edmonton (Auto-set: )
 - Current Date/Time: 2018-11-29 15:44:52
 - Error Reporting: 32767

SOAP adapter: 
 - QuickBooks_Adapter_Server_Builtin

Registered handler functions: 
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => authenticate
    [2] => sendRequestXML
    [3] => receiveResponseXML
    [4] => connectionError
    [5] => getLastError
    [6] => closeConnection
    [7] => serverVersion
    [8] => clientVersion
)

Detected input: 


Timestamp: 
 - 2018-11-29 15:44:52 -- process 0.07853
```

Comment: I may have fixed it. Laravel was forcing text/html, so I did: `return response($contents)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');` and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error:

`Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', but expected 'text/xml'.`

Means that *something* is sending a `Content-Type: text/html` header, and overriding the `Content-Type: text/xml` header the framework is trying to send.

Laravel is probably doing this. Try adjusting your response/route in Laravel to return `text/xml` instead:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses

Example:

```
return response($contents)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```